# How to set position on MKMap

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I have 4 coordinates of rect. 
like

```
north="55.9504356" south="55.5485293" east="38.1289043" west="37.1044291"
```

how i can set map position in this rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google goecoding gives me viewport `<LatLonBox north="55.9504356" south="55.5485293" east="38.1289043" west="37.1044291"/>`  and center of region Russia, Moscow.

```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D centerOfRegion = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([data.coordinatesLongitude doubleValue],[data.coordinatesLatitude doubleValue]);     //37.6166667,55.7500000

    //N+E S+W for get distance between
    double lat1 = [[data.squareArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double lng1 = [[data.squareArray objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];

    double lat2 = [[data.squareArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    double lng2 = [[data.squareArray objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];

    CLLocation *firstLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lng1] autorelease];
    CLLocation *secondLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:lng2] autorelease];
    //   and /2 to make a little smaller viewport
    CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];

    [map setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerOfRegion, distance/2, distance/2)];
```

so a got  centered region and normaly size of region.

My solution is so, hopeits can help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your coordinates. Try to obtain a center of rect somehow. Here's the sample of my code:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {[neighborhood.Latitude doubleValue], [neighborhood.Longitude doubleValue]};
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 15000, 15000);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

as you can see you point out a center of rect and the distance from center in meters.

Comment: This method make center of rect and distance, but i need exactly rect by 4 coordinates. Thx, but this one not response to my situation.

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion
A structure that defines which portion of the map to display.

typedef struct {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
} MKCoordinateRegion;
So as you can see you there is no way to create this structure in some other way

Comment: Stas gave a very reasonable answer, unless your question is not clear. What do you mean "can set map position in this rectangle"?

Comment: i got 4 points ( N S E W ) that describe an rectangle. And i want set screen on map by this points.

Comment: Zhenya you have got a data in wrong(or just not suitable for your task) format you should type a couple strings of code to convert it. That's a pretty easy task I think...